# Mi app no guarda los datos como debe ser en firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

Tengo mi aplicacion publicada en la play store y al enviarle los datos a la cloud firestore de firebase no me los guarda con los objetos que previamente estan nombrados desde mi clase java, mi aplicacion corre muy bien y sin fallos al intalarla desde el android studio al telefono pero posee problemas al descargarla desde la play store, ademas guarda los datos con letras.

Asi guarda mis datos en el firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es mi clase:

public class Usuario {

```
public String fotoPerfilURL;
public String nombre;
public String telefono;
public String correo;
public String fechaDeNacimiento;
public String genero;
public String keyUsuario;
public String key;

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(String fotoPerfilURL, String nombre, String telefono, String correo, String fechaDeNacimiento, String genero, String keyUsuario, String key) {
    this.fotoPerfilURL = fotoPerfilURL;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.correo = correo;
    this.fechaDeNacimiento = fechaDeNacimiento;
    this.genero = genero;
    this.keyUsuario = keyUsuario;
    this.key = key;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getFotoPerfilURL() {
    return fotoPerfilURL;
}

public void setFotoPerfilURL(String fotoPerfilURL) {
    this.fotoPerfilURL = fotoPerfilURL;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public String getFechaDeNacimiento() {
    return fechaDeNacimiento;
}

public void setFechaDeNacimiento(String fechaDeNacimiento) {
    this.fechaDeNacimiento = fechaDeNacimiento;
}

public String getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(String genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}

public String getKeyUsuario() {
    return keyUsuario;
}

public void setKeyUsuario(String keyUsuario) {
    this.keyUsuario = keyUsuario;
}

public String getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
```

}

Aqui es donde envio mis datos:

```
Usuario usuario = new Usuario(user.getPhotoUrl().toString(),Snombre,telefono,user.getEmail(),Sfecha,Sgenero,key, "00" + i1);
                databaseReference.child(Constantes.NODO_USUARIOS).child(key).setValue(usuario);

                dbFire.collection(Constantes.NODO_USUARIOS).document(key).set(usuario);
```

Manifests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=".Utilidades.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_daanjulogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_daanjulogo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/TemaLogin">

    <service
        android:name=".Service.ServiceWordS"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".Service.BootBroadcast">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-6226761982005642~6530269665"/>

    <activity android:name=".Activity.LoginActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="d189f40d16f4dbf0b72e6f4dd8b01e51" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.PersonalActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity.MensajeriaIndividualActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.ProfileUserActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.FriendActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity.CrearWordSpaceActivity" />
</application>
```

ProGuard:

-keep class com.google.firebase.example.fireeats.model.** { *; }
-printconfiguration ~/tmp/full-r8-config.txt

Mil gracias.

Comment: Tu problema es que al compilar la app para subirla al store se esta ofuscando el codigo y los nombres de las clases, propiedades y variables son cambiadas por letras o conjuntos de letras, por eso luego firebase sube los datos pero con los key mal puestos. Sube el contenido de tu archivo ProGuard para que te pueda ayudar a corregirlo

Comment: Que contenido subo al ProGuard ?

Comment: el problema esta en lo que dice Erick , fijate que el proguard no ofusque ninguna clase que use Firebase para enviar o recibir datos, ademas, una recomendación, cuando haces el signed build apk, siempre pruebalo nuevamente en el dispositivo antes de subirlo a produccion en el playstore , un saludo